# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `songs` where `id` = 5 limit 1)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get specific data from the database by using column `SongID` when a user clicks a link but I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `songs` where `id` = 5 limit 1)

The Controller Class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class SongsController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        $songs = DB::table('songs')->get();
        return view('songs.index', compact('songs','name'));
    }
    public function show($id)
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        $song = DB::table('songs')->find($id);
        return view('songs.show', compact('song','name'));
    }

    private function getName()
    {
        $name = 'Tupac Amaru Shakur';
        return $name;
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('songs', function($table)
            {
                $table->increments('SongID');
                $table->string('SongTitle')->index();
                $table->string('Lyrics')->nullable();
                $table->timestamp('created_at');
            });
    }
```

Comment: How does your table schema look like? Obviously you seem to be missing an `id` column in your table for some reason....

Comment: I do not have a column called id in my table, instead i have the SongID

Answer (score 129, accepted):

When you use `find()`, it automatically assumes your primary key column is going to be `id`.  In order for this to work correctly, you should set your primary key  in your model.

So in `Song.php`, within the class, add the line...

```
protected $primaryKey = 'SongID';
```

If there is any possibility of changing your schema, I'd highly recommend naming all your primary key columns `id`, it's what Laravel assumes and will probably save you from more headaches down the road.

Comment: It is the superb solution and the best answer.

Comment: This is also true with errors you might be having with Resource or Collection as Laravel tends to use the same Model.

Comment: This solution also applies to other scenarios where the same error occurs. In my case it was a CreateOrUpdate statement which failed because I didnt have an primary key defined and it defaults back to checking for `where 'id' is null`

Answer (score 10):

Just Go to Model file of the corresponding Controller and check  the  primary key filed name

such as

```
protected $primaryKey = 'info_id';
```

here info id is field name available in database  table

More info can be found at "Primary Keys" section of [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#primary-keys).

Answer (score 4):

```
$song = DB::table('songs')->find($id);
```

here you use method `find($id)`

for Laravel, if you use this method, you should have column named 'id' and set it as primary key, so then you'll be able to use method `find()`

otherwise use `where('SongID', $id)` instead of `find($id)`

Comment: @CJ Suspend this statement returns nothing from database.

Comment: `$song = DB::table('songs')->where('SongID', $id)->first()`  That should return a model (as long as there is something in your database with that id).  Then you should be able to get the property of that with `$song->SongTitle`

Answer (score 0):

`protected $primaryKey = 'SongID';`

After adding to my model to tell the primary key because it was taking id(SongID) by default

Answer (score 0):

I am running laravel 5.8 and i experienced the same problem. The solution that worked for me is as follows :

1. I used bigIncrements('id') to define my primary key.
2. I used  unsignedBigInteger('user_id') to define the foreign
   referenced key.

   ```
       Schema::create('generals', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('general_name');
           $table->string('status');
           $table->timestamps();
       });


       Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->unsignedBigInteger('general_id');
           $table->foreign('general_id')->references('id')->on('generals');
           $table->string('category_name');
           $table->string('status');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   ```

I hope this helps out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB::table as mentioned above but without the 'find'

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', 123)->update(['role_id' => 2]);
```