# Get multiple foreign key values and output them on view

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm making a reservation system, this is the table that I'm currently using.I can't get the foreign key value of client payment. I already put the relationship in the models.

**Booking**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class booking extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['clientID', 'checkInDate', 'checkOutDate', 'roomsCount', 'roomTypeID', 'adultsCount', 'childrenCount', 'amenityID', 'paymentID'];


    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client','clientID');
    }
    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Payment');
    }
    public function amenities()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Amenities');
    }
```

**Client**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class client extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['fullNmae', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phoneNumber', 'emailAddress'];
  public function booking()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Booking');
  }
}
```

**Payment**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class payment extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['clientID', 'paymentMethod', 'invoiceNum', 'accountName', 'amountPaid', 'datePaid', 'payment_image', 'comments'];
  public function booking()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Booking');
  }
}
```

I'm currently using this to access the foreign key

```
$bookingDetail = booking::with('client', 'payment')->get();
        return view('detail')
        ->with('bookingDetail', $bookingDetail);
```

**view**

```
{{ $bookingDetail->payment->paymentMethod }}
```

**Error I'm Getting**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clients` where `clients`.`id` in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17))

Is this the right way to do it? or am I missing something. I'm new to laravel so I don't know if this is the right way to do it

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-id-in-where-clause-s

Comment: I tried doing that. But now i get this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payments.booking_bookingID' in 'where clause'

Comment: what is primary key of clients table?

Comment: I'ts `protected $primaryKey = 'clientID';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a relation, laravel able to detect your foreign keys using "methodName" + "_id" structure.

But if your foreign key doesn't match with this pattern, then you have to specify the keys manually..

```
public function booking()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Booking',$foreignKey,$ownerKey);
}

public function payment()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Payment',$foreignKey, $ownerKey);
}
```