# I have a problem with my laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I'm using laravel as my web project, and I have an issue when I update my database.

I have an error message on my postman after posting data. Here is the message.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `data_transaksis` set `jumlah_transaksi` = 10000, `info` = Transaksi 2 Mysql Update, `data_transaksis`.`updated_at` = 2021-05-23 03:59:54 where `id` is null)
```

This is my function code to update a row on a database.

```
$dataTransaksi = DataTransaksi::where('transact_id', $request->transact_id)->first();
$dataTransaksi->jumlah_transaksi = $request->jumlah_transaksi;
$dataTransaksi->info = $request->info;
$dataTransaksi->save();

return response($dataTransaksi, 200)->header('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

I don't know what's going on with my code, i search for 'transact_id' on my query builder, but the error message shows that I search for 'id'. It's odd. Any solution for my problem?

Edit:
This is my table structure.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpA3D.jpg

Comment: do you have `id` column in your db & what is value of `transact_id`

Comment: i don't have a column named 'id' on my table. The primary key of my 'data_transaksi' table is 'transact_id'. that's it, no 'id' column or what so ever.

Comment: try to print `DataTransaksi::where('transact_id', $request->transact_id)->toSql()` and this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-id-in-where-clause-s?rq=1

Comment: select * from `data_transaksis` where `transact_id` = ?

Comment: I forgot to tell u, this is the example of my post body on postman

{
    "transact_id": "1-1-2",
    "book_id": "1-1",
    "jumlah_transaksi": 10000,
    "info": "Transaksi 2 Mysql Update"
}

Comment: you have set `protected $primaryKey = 'transact_id'` in your class ,  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Comment: my $request->transact_id value is exist, not an question mark. when I return the variable, it's exist.

Comment: my class? did u mean model? I add it and error message says 'illegal offset type'

Comment: `?` for later binding to prevent any sql injection so i will suggest you to set your primary key in class `protected $primaryKey = 'transact_id' because laravel assume `id` as primary key default .

Comment: yes in your model

Comment: nvm, it's work now, wrong syntax. It's solved by ur solution. thx alot mate.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to set your primary key in the model like `protected $primaryKey = 'transact_id'` because laravel assumes `id` as primary key by default.

Check this [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys) for more info on laravel and primary keys.