# Populate dropdown options fail on second try on livewire 3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Here I use livewire 3 to populate parent-child dropdown. But I found error when I trigger the parent data for the second times.
This error
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'areas.id' in 'where clause'`  but I dont have or need `ID` coz my dropdown only need `name` from DB.

Here's my view

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="ro" class="col-lg-5 col-form-label">RO</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <select class="form-select" id="ro" name="ro" wire:model='form.ro'
            wire:change="changeEvent($event.target.value)">
            <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
            @foreach ($regionals as $ro)
            <option value="{{ $ro->ro_name }}">{{ $ro->ro_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('form.ro')
        <span class="text-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="ao" class="col-lg-5 col-form-label">AO</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <select class="form-select" id="ao" name="ao" wire:model='form.ao'>
            @if($areas->isEmpty())
            <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
            @endif

            @foreach ($areas as $ao)
            <option value="{{ $ao->ao_group }}">{{ $ao->ao_group }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('form.ao')
        <span class="text-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

And my class

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Area;
use App\Models\Brand;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Livewire\Forms\CreateAkuisisiForm;

#[Title('Outlet Universe - Add Outlet')]
class NonKontrakCreate extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public CreateAkuisisiForm $form;

    public Collection $areas;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->areas = collect();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.non-kontrak-create', [
            'brands' => Brand::all(),
            'regionals' => Area::select('ro_name')->groupBy('ro_name')->orderBy('ro_name','asc')->get(),
        ]);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->form->save();
    }

    public function changeEvent($value)
    {
        $this->areas = Area::where('ro_name', $value)->get();
    }
}
```

I just want when I change ro dropdown, I can populate the area's data.
My code war running in first time after page reload, RO dropdown was trigger the `function changeEvent` but when I try to change RO data, always error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'areas.id' in 'where clause'` I dont know why, because I dont use ID for query parameter. Please advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[42S22\]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select \* from \`songs\` where \`id\` = 5 limit 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347253/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-id-in-where-clause-s)

Comment: My table doesn't have ID by default

Comment: Does livewire require `id` by default in the table?

Comment: what is the primary key name for `Area`?

Answer (score -1):

Hi Here is my modification to your livewire components

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Livewire;
    
    use App\Models\Area;
    use App\Models\Brand;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
    use Livewire\Attributes\Title;
    use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
    use App\Livewire\Forms\CreateAkuisisiForm;
    
    #[Title('Outlet Universe - Add Outlet')]
    class NonKontrakCreate extends Component
    {
        use WithFileUploads;
    
        public CreateAkuisisiForm $form;
    
        public Collection $areas;

        public $brands;

        public $regionals;

        public $ro = '';
        public $ao = '';

    
    
        public function mount()
        {
            $this->areas = collect();
            $this->brands = Brand::all();
            $this->regionals = Area::select('ro_name')->groupBy('ro_name')->orderBy('ro_name', 'asc')->get();
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.non-kontrak-create');
        }
    
        public function store()
        {
            $this->form->ro = $this->ro;
            $this->form->ao = $this->ao;

            $this->form->save();
        }
    
        public function updatedRo($value)
        {
            $this->areas = Area::where('ro_name', $value)->get();
        }
    }
```

Here is view update

RO
    
        
            -- Pilih --
            @foreach ($regionals as $ro)
            ro_name }}">{{ $ro->ro_name }}
            @endforeach
        
        @error('form.ro')
        
            **{{ $message }}**
        
        @enderror

```
<div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="ao" class="col-lg-5 col-form-label">AO</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <select class="form-select" id="ao" name="ao" wire:model='ao'>
            @if($areas->isEmpty())
            <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
            @endif

            @foreach ($areas as $ao)
            <option value="{{ $ao->ao_group }}">{{ $ao->ao_group }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('form.ao')
        <span class="text-danger" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it hope it will work.